# Script to open encrypted excel file, that has a dynamic filename ending in "mmddyyyy"

Tags: excel, powershell, vbscript, ssis, encryption

Hi I need a script for my SSIS package that will open my encrypted excel file, that has a dynamic filename ending in "mmddyyyy". 
I have a powershell script that will open and reset the password using the filename, but I do not know how to use a dynamic filename there.
Also, I think I would prefer a vb script that will open the file and remove the password (or maybe not as long as I can extract the data while it is open?) as I will likely set it up as a SQL job to extract and send to sql daily.

Here is an example of the stripped down code:

```
objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 
$objExcel.Visible = $True 
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $False 
$MMDDYYYY=[DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("MMddyyyy")    
$objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\files\Reporting\Census\Daily_$MMDDYYYY.xls",0,$False,‌​1,"password")
$Workbook.Password = ""
$strPath="\\\files\Reporting\Census\Daily_$MMDDYYYY.xls" 
$a.activeworkbook.SaveAs($strPath) 
$objExcel.Quit() 
$Workbook=$Null 
$objExcel=$Null 
[GC]::Collect()
```

Powershell also displays a "fullyqualifiederrorid": InvokeMethodOnNull error message.

Comment: What is your specific question? Powershell allows the use of arguments, so you could pass the name into the script... What code do you have so far?

Comment: My powershell script needs to open a file daily , change the password, delete some rows, and then save with no password. I can do everything except open a dynamic filename with the mmddyyyy ext at the end of each file.  REPLACE:                                  $Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\files\SHC\Daily_04262013.xls",0,$False,1,"password") with code to open  ("\\files\SHC\Daily_mmddyyyy.xls",0,$False,1,"password") where mmddyyyy is always "yesterday".

Answer (score 2):

You can set a variable with the current date - 1 like this:

```
$MMddyyyy=[DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("MMddyyyy")
$objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\files\SHC\Daily_$MMddyyyy.xls",0,$False,1,"password")
```

More "Powershell-y", using Get-Date instead of the [DateTime]::Today object.

```
$MMddyyyy=(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMddyyyy")
$objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\files\SHC\Daily_$MMddyyyy.xls",0,$False,1,"password")
```

Comment: +1 `(Get-Date)` would be more PoSh than `[DateTime]::Today`, though.

Comment: Hi, Thank you!  It works fine for opening the file, but won't save:                                                             $a = $Workbook.SaveAs("\\files\SHC\Daily_$YYYYMMDD.xls")                                 it presents a RuntimeException???

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Added a Get_date version.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Looks like you already answered this too in 2012! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272960/powershell-excel-automation-save-workbook-by-date

Comment: @LornaRobinson Does your userid that you run this with have rights to the network UNC path? Sometimes powershell has issues with permissions to network drives...

Comment: Hi, yes, my userid does have the required permissions.  Powershell also displays a "fullyqualifiederrorid": InvokeMethodOnNull if that helps?

Comment: I think it has to do with the uninitialized $a variable? Shouldn't that be $objExcel instead?

Comment: It's working - I started from scratch and added the variable and everything is working properly now, with the $a variable as it was.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a problem in which I needed to open an Excel password-protected file. However even following the answers in this post and the duplicate ([open a password protected Excel in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998625/open-a-password-protected-excel-in-powershell)), it still prompted me for a password. 
I solved by adding the 6th parameter WriteResPassword. My final code was:

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.DisplayAlerts=$False
$wb=$xl.Workbooks.open("$myFile",3,$false,5,"$mypassword","$mypassword")
```

Hope this helps anyone else who struggles with password protected files in Powershell.