# open a password protected Excel in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, password-protection

I'm trying to open a password protected excel sheet in powershell and output a report on how many rows are in the sheet.

the script works absolutely fine if the sheet isn't password protected but I can't seem to get powershell to open it if there is a password set.

my current script is

```
$Report = "S:\Business Support\excel tests\MI Tool - Live.csv"
$path = "S:\Business Support\excel tests"
[Array]$Results = $null
$excelSheets = Get-Childitem -Path $path -Include "MI Tool - Live.xlsm" -Recurse
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$password = "blablabla"
$updatelinks = 0


foreach($excelSheet in $excelSheets)
{
 $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelSheet,$updatelinks,$password)
 $rowCount = $null

  $worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Data")
  $rowMax = ($worksheet.usedRange.rows).count
  $rowCount += $rowMax

$Results += New-Object Psobject -Property @{
    "File Name"=$excelSheet.Name
    "Row Count"=$rowCount}
$excelSheet.Name
$workbook.Sheets.count
$rowCount
}
$excel.quit()
Stop-Process -Name EXCEL -Force
$Results | select "File Name","Row Count" | Export-Csv $Report -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Open method of Workbooks class failed"
At line:3 char:35
+  $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open <<<< ($excelSheet,$updatelinks,$password)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:37
+   $worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item <<<< ("Data")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

If I take out the $password variable it works but I then have to enter the password manually.

Comment: try running `$password = 'blablabla'` - do you get same result?

Comment: unfortunately, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Open overload is incorrect. The password is the 5th variable. [Have a look at MSDN to see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)

> expression .Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, **Password**, WriteResPassword, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Origin, Delimiter, Editable, Notify, Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)

So you would need to populate ReadOnly and Format first I believe. You would have to populate those values.

```
$excel.Workbooks.open($path,0,0,5,$password)
```

Look at the MSDN to understand what the values represent in the 2,3 and 4 positions.

Comment: excellent thank you. Apologies if it was a duplicate question but I could really find an answer that explained it as well as here!

Comment: That is why I left the answer here. The dupe does have this code but does not explain the issue. The dupe was weak but the answer contained what you needed to see.

Comment: @Matt - what to do if I have only VBA code password protected but I need to access it from powershell?