# Open password protected Excel xlsx file w/Powershell and save as csv without password

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a password protected Excel file (Office 2019, xlsx file). I would like to create a Powershell script to open the file with the password and then save it as a csv without the password in a new directory. I tried to follow the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998625/open-a-password-protected-excel-in-powershell) but this was not working for me. I do not have a lot of experience with Powershell, any insight is appreciated.

I wanted to update this here for anyone looking for a similar solution, the solution is below. I was surprised I could not find a simple how-to for this one anywhere.

And to the critic of my original post - if you had written something like this in the past, the answer would have been a simple copy and paste of an existing script you might have used. I have a large repository of these types of scripts myself and share them frequently with co-workers and community, so I was looking for somebody that may have had something similar to share. You apparently did not so there was no point in your response.

```
$filepath = "C:\MyDailyFile\Blah.xlsx"
$password = "omgpassword"

try {
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $true
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $true

## Open target password protected workbook
## [Type}::Missing are placeholders for positional parameters. See the Workbook class for more detail.

$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $password)
$sheet = $wb.ActiveSheet

## Save the open workbook in a new directory without a password
## and change the file type to CSV

$wb.SaveAs("C:\MyDailyFile\BlahCommaDelim",6,"")

## The second property of the SaveAs class (6) corresponds to a type "csv". The above results in the following SaveAs path: 
## C:\MyDailyFile\BlahCommaDelim.csv
## More information on XlFileFormat parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.XlFileFormat

$excel.Quit()

} finally {
    $sheet, $wb, $excel | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -ne $null) {
            [void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PLEASE, post your code [wrapped in code formatting markers] AND post any errors [as text in code formatting] AND add some details about what "not working for me" means ... [*grin*]

Comment: Grizzlerzz, what Lee_Dailey is saying is not really a critique, it's the rules of Stackoverflow as documented in the following: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - 
[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Yet good to know you already found that dupe. Folks are willing to help, but, you know, rules and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always step through your code one block at a time to make sure you are getting back what you'd expect.

***I am using my poor man's debug use case leveraging*** [variable squeezing](https://ridicurious.com/2017/06/30/3-ways-to-store-display-results-infrom-a-powershell-variable-at-the-same-time/), meaning, assigning the results to a variable while automatically outputting to the screen. You will note this all works as expected, and Lee's ask of what errors you were getting is s prudent ask.

Your statement:

> I tried to follow the question here but this was not working for me.

... is not really a clarifying statement.

```
($XlsFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter 'File*.xl*')
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name        
----                -------------         ------ ----        
-a----        28-Apr-20     15:49           9811 FileData.xlsx                                                                                                      
-a----        28-Apr-20     15:50          16384 FileDataProtected.xlsx 
#>

($XlsFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter 'File*.csv')
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name        
----                -------------         ------ ----        
-a----        06-Apr-20     00:54            260 FileData.csv  
#>

($filepath = 'D:\Temp\FileDataProtected.xlsx')
($password = 'omgpassword')
<#
# Results

D:\Temp\FileDataProtected.xlsx
omgpassword
#>


$excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible       = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $true
```

Why are you typecasting here? It's really not warranted.

```
# ($wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $password))
<#
# Results

Application                      : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator                          : 1480803660
Parent                           : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
AcceptLabelsInFormulas           : False
ActiveChart                      : 
ActiveSheet                      : System.__ComObject
Author                           : 
AutoUpdateFrequency              : 0
AutoUpdateSaveChanges            : 
ChangeHistoryDuration            : 0
BuiltinDocumentProperties        : System.__ComObject
Charts                           : System.__ComObject
CodeName                         : 
_CodeName                        : 
CommandBars                      : 
Comments                         : 
ConflictResolution               : 1
Container                        : 
CreateBackup                     : False
CustomDocumentProperties         : System.__ComObject
Date1904                         : False
DialogSheets                     : System.__ComObject
DisplayDrawingObjects            : -4104
FileFormat                       : 51
FullName                         : D:\Temp\FileDataProtected.xlsx
...
#>

($wb    = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath,0,0,5,$password))
<#
# Results

Application                      : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator                          : 1480803660
Parent                           : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
AcceptLabelsInFormulas           : False
ActiveChart                      : 
ActiveSheet                      : System.__ComObject
Author                           : 
AutoUpdateFrequency              : 0
AutoUpdateSaveChanges            : 
ChangeHistoryDuration            : 0
BuiltinDocumentProperties        : System.__ComObject
Charts                           : System.__ComObject
CodeName                         : 
_CodeName                        : 
CommandBars                      : 
Comments                         : 
ConflictResolution               : 1
Container                        : 
CreateBackup                     : False
CustomDocumentProperties         : System.__ComObject
Date1904                         : False
DialogSheets                     : System.__ComObject
DisplayDrawingObjects            : -4104
FileFormat                       : 51
FullName                         : D:\Temp\FileDataProtected.xlsx
...
#>
```

You are not using this anywhere in what you have posted, sooo, why do this? 
It takes a long time to complete as well for something you are not using.

```
#>
($sheet = $wb.ActiveSheet) 
<#
# Results

Application                       : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator                           : 1480803660
Parent                            : System.__ComObject
CodeName                          : 
_CodeName                         : 
Index                             : 1
Name                              : FileData
...
#>



$wb.SaveAs('D:\Temp\FileDataUnProtected.csv',6,'')
<#
# Results
```

When you do this, of course, Excel will yell at you about data loss by switching from Xlsx to CSV.

```
# Clean-up
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
<#
# Results

6
#>


($XlsFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter 'File*.csv')
<#
# Results


    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        06-Apr-20     00:54            260 FileData.csv
-a----        28-Apr-20     16:21            129 FileDataUnProtected.csv
#>

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\FileDataUnProtected.csv'
<#
# Results

0 minutes
0 minutes
1 day and 19 hours
1 day and 2 hours
1 day and 20 hours
1 day and 23 hours
13 hours
2 days
20 hours
#>

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\FileDataUnProtected.csv'
<#
# Results

0 minutes         
1 day and 19 hours
1 day and 2 hours 
1 day and 20 hours
1 day and 23 hours
13 hours          
2 days            
20 hours 
#>
```

Lastly, this makes little sense to do since you only have one COM object to dispose of, the others are just variables and should be cleaned up using the Remove-Variable cmdlet

```
finally {
$sheet, $wb, $excel | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -ne $null) {
        [void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the detail here, this is the kind of thing I was looking for, coupled with a functional script task. Like I noted originally, PowerShell is not my area of expertise so for the sake of saving myself a few hours I was hoping to find somebody who could share something they already created. The solution I came up with is a piecemeal solution from different blogs which is why there are superfluous steps...honestly I was pleasantly surprised it worked in the first place. Again, thanks for the feedback this will help me be a better debugger of my PowerShell in the future.

Comment: No worries. We, volunteers, do what we can to help and learn. Getting ramped up on new Tech just takes time. Jump on Youtube and do a search for 'PowerShell videos', beginning, intermediate, advanced, GUI, file & folder management, etc. Also, become very familiar with the MS powershellgallery.com and this from Microsoft. [Windows PowerShell Survival Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx) - 
[More PowerShell learning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/more-powershell-learning?view=powershell-7)

Comment: BTW, if this solved your use case, please be sure to mark as your accepted answer for those who find themselves in the same position.